# HBASE import using SQOOP

Tags: hbase, sqoop

I am trying to import into a HBASE table using sqoop import. As part of it i will need to provide the HBASE specific parameters using hbase-site.xml. There is no argument that allows providing this parameter on sqoop import. How is this specified for import ? Is it a parameter that is provided on the command line (HBASE_CONF_DIR or the like). HDP is the platform that is used.

Edits- SQOOP  Command. Note that my HBASE is in a different cluster , different from where i am running this.

```
sqoop --options-file  my_db_opts.txt --query "SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL" --hbase-row-key   "SYSDATE"   --hbase-table   "MASTER_2"  --column-family "0"  --hbase-create-table  -m   1
```

and the exception

```
17/08/13 14:58:19 WARN zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Possibly transient ZooKeeper, quorum=localhost:2181, exception=org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase
17/08/13 14:58:20 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
17/08/13 14:58:20 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1125)
```

Comment: I don't think you need to provide the `.xml` file. Can you share your import command.

Comment: made the edits to add the command and the stack trace i get. I also added the hbase-site.xml into /etc/sqoop/conf/hbase-site.xml

Comment: does not matter , --hbase-create-table is used. Will be created if it does not exist. The error is a failure in ZK to lookup hbase regions

Comment: not really ! looks like some services might be not running and that's why you are getting this error. Please check the Zookeeper and Hbase service.

Comment: Nope , i am able to do both hbase shell as well as phoenix-sqlline and query tables normally. Just that i need to point to the right ZK node and get access to hbase-unsecure  root

Comment: may be, but error log says no zookeeper service is running on client host so by default it is connecting to localhost, therefore it is failing.

Comment: This is the similar error, see if it helps you. https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/86429/cannot-connect-to-zookeeper-server-from-zookeeper.html